# Popup goes behind stage only on Mac but not on Windows/Linux in Full Screen

Tags: linux, windows, macos, popup, javafx

I'm extending javafx.stage.Popup to display a popup message. The entire app works fine on Windows and Ubuntu but on Mac Popups go behind the current stage when the app is full screen. I've tried using z-index,.toFront(), setting owner window and everything. But the popups just never showup! Same problem is with javafx.stage.FileChooser. Since the app must be fullscreen all the time, what is the solution?

**EDIT:** In another page,the textfield has cursor blinking in fullscreen but does not receive typed keys! And this happens **ONLY** in full screen! If I lose fullscreen, the textfield recieves typed keys. Quite annoying :( Please suggest if I should file a bug or something

I've figured out workaround for popup but problem persists for DirectoryChooser/FileChooser.

This is the class that extends Popup:

```
public class PopupDisplay extends Popup
{
String Title=new String("Information");
String Prompt=new String("Prompt Text");
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorMain;
@FXML
private Label lblTitle=new Label();
@FXML
private Font x1;
@FXML
private Label lblPrompt=new Label();
@FXML
private Button btnOk;
@FXML
private GridPane gridMain;
@FXML
private HBox hboxTitle;
static PopupDisplay instance;
private ColorDxDesktop application;
public void show(Stage stage, String titleKey,String promptKey, Locale enLocale)
{
    AnchorPane root;
    FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
    ResourceBundle rb;
    
    Prompt=promptKey;
    Title=titleKey;
    try
    {
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/sc/colordx/resources/"));
        rb=ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.sc.colordx.resources.lang.Popup",application.getLocale());
       
        loader.setResources(rb);
        PopupController.prompt=Prompt;
        PopupController.title=Title;
        
        root = (AnchorPane)loader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/sc/colordx/presentation/Popup.fxml").openStream());
        getScene().setRoot(root);
        PopupController popupController=loader.getController();
        
        
            
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        root.setPrefWidth(application.getStage().getWidth());
        root.setPrefHeight(application.getStage().getHeight());
        Node n=root.getChildren().get(0);
        n.setLayoutX(screenBounds.getWidth()/2.5);
        n.setLayoutY((screenBounds.getHeight()/2.5));
        //root.toFront();
        
        show(stage);

        
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static PopupDisplay getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}
@FXML
private void hide(MouseEvent event) 
{
    this.hide();
}
public void showInProgress()
{
    PopupController.showInProgress();
    
    
}
```

And this is the FXML for Popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorMain" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.sc.colordx.controller.PopupController">
  <children>
    <GridPane id="GridPane" fx:id="gridMain" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="309.0" layoutY="330.0" minWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color:black;" styleClass="visibleWindow, gridpane, gridpane-boder" vgap="20.0">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="lblPrompt" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="271.0" text="%keyPrompt" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
          <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" fx:id="x1" />
          </font>
          <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="6.0" left="6.0" right="6.0" top="6.0" />
          </GridPane.margin>
        </Label>
        <HBox id="HBox" fx:id="hboxButtons" alignment="CENTER" spacing="7.0" style="" styleClass="hbox" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
          <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnOk" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#exitOkay" text="%keyYes" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button id="btnOk" fx:id="btnCancel" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#hide" text="%keyNo" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
          </children>
          <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
          </padding>
          <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@../resources/css/Popup.css" />
          </stylesheets>
        </HBox>
        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" cache="true" cacheHint="QUALITY" progress="0.0" visible="false" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="300.0" />
          </GridPane.margin>
        </ProgressIndicator>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <padding>
        <Insets />
      </padding>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
       <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
      </children>
      <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../resources/css/Popup.css" />
      </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing I was getting with Popup while running JavaFx application in MAC so what I did was created new Stage (dummy/invisible with height and width = 0) with `initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);` and bind my popup with that. Everytime I need to display popup I use `dummyStage.show();` and `popup.toFront();` so it will cause a trick to handle my problem in mac.

Comment: yeah I know workarounds. For ex. I'm using stackpane and adding current stage root and popup screen root to it to show the popup. But I need a proper solution using Popup itself because I cant apply workarounds with FileChooser.